# Reconstruct ComboBoxItems based on a property (+ method return value) with different background colour

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have these **Study Points** as a resource in the **app.xaml** file:

```
<x:Array x:Key="StudyPoints" Type="local:StudyPointItem">
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "0" Title = "No study point assigned" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "1" Title = "Accurate Reading" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "2" Title = "Words Clearly Spoken" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "3" Title = "Correct Pronunciation" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "4" Title = "Fluent Delivery" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "5" Title = "Appropriate Pausing" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "6" Title = "Proper Sense Stress" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "7" Title = "Principal Ideas Emphasized" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "8" Title = "Suitable Volume" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "9" Title = "Modulation" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "10" Title = "Enthusiasm" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "11" Title = "Warmth And Feeling" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "12" Title = "Gestures and Facial Expressions" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "13" Title = "Visual Contact" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "14" Title = "Naturalness" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "15" Title = "Good Personal Appearance" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "16" Title = "Poise" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "17" Title = "Use of Microphone" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "18" Title = "Use of Bible in Replying" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "19" Title = "Use of Bible Encouraged" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "20" Title = "Scriptures Effectively Introduced" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "21" Title = "Scriptures Read With Proper Emphasis" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "22" Title = "Scriptures Correctly Applied" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "23" Title = "Practical Value Made Clear" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "24" Title = "Choice of Words" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "25" Title = "Use of an Outline" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "26" Title = "Logical Development of Material" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "27" Title = "Extemporaneous Delivery" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "28" Title = "Conversational Manner" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "29" Title = "Voice Quality" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "30" Title = "Interest Shown in the Other Person" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "31" Title = "Respect Shown to Others" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "32" Title = "Expressed With Conviction" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "33" Title = "Tactful Yet Firm" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "34" Title = "Upbuilding And Positive" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "35" Title = "Repetition for Emphasis" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "36" Title = "Theme Developed" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "37" Title = "Main Points Made to Stand Out" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "38" Title = "Interest - Arousing Introduction" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "39" Title = "Effective Conclusion" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "40" Title = "Accuracy of Statement" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "41" Title = "Understandable to Others" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "42" Title = "Informative to Your Audience" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "43" Title = "Use of Assigned Material" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "44" Title = "Effective Use of Questions" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "45" Title = "Illustrations / Examples That Teach" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "46" Title = "Illustrations From Familiar Situations" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "47" Title = "Effective Use of Visual Aids" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "48" Title = "Reasoning Manner" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "49" Title = "Sound Arguments Given" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "50" Title = "Effort To Reach the Heart" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "51" Title = "Accurately Timed, Properly Proportioned" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "52" Title = "Effective Exhortation" />
    <local:StudyPointItem Number = "53" Title = "Audience Encouraged and Strengthened" />
</x:Array>
```

In my **ViewModel** I have a couple of methods that are used to build two filtered versions of the list:

```
private void InitReadingStudyPointsList()
{
    ReadingStudyPointsList = new List<StudyPointItem>();

    StudyPointItem[] arrayStudyItems = (StudyPointItem[])Application.Current.Resources["StudyPoints"];

    for (int iStudyNumber = 0; iStudyNumber < 18; iStudyNumber++)
        ReadingStudyPointsList.Add(arrayStudyItems[iStudyNumber]);

}

private void InitStudentStudyPointsList()
{
    StudentStudyPointsList = new List<StudyPointItem>();

    StudyPointItem[] arrayStudyItems = (StudyPointItem[])Application.Current.Resources["StudyPoints"];

    for (int iStudyNumber = 0; iStudyNumber < 52; iStudyNumber++)
    {
        if (iStudyNumber != 7)
            StudentStudyPointsList.Add(arrayStudyItems[iStudyNumber]);
    }
}
```

And, on the main window, I use these filtered lists in ComboBoxes as item source. For example:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingStudyPointsList}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Now, within my **ViewModel** is a **property** of type `Student`. It is kept up to date as you select a student on the `DataGrid`.

The `Student` has a public method:

```
bool IsWorkingOnStudyPoint(int iStudy)
```

At the moment, my `ComboBox` looks something like:

[image: Combo]

This is what I would like to achieve:

> As the user selects a student, the `ComboBox` updates the list of study points so that, any that return `IsWorkingOnStudy(x)` as `true` set the `ComboBoxItem` background as yellow. Manually constructed example:

[image: Combo with highlighting]

I am trying to establish the right way to handle this.

### Update

I am getting there:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingStudyPointsList}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Number}" />
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StudyPointWorkingOn}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag"/>
                        <Binding/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And for the `ValueConverter` (test code):

```
namespace OCLMEditor.ValueConverters
{
    class StudyPointWorkingOn : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int iStudyNumber = (int)values[0];
            Console.WriteLine(values[1].ToString());
            if(iStudyNumber % 3 == 0)            
                return (SolidColorBrush)System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Aqua;

            return null;

            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

But my second parameter `<Binding />` is wrong. That is the `StudyPointItem` object and what i want to pass is what was specified for the `ComboBox` itself:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
```

Specifically, I would like to pass as my second binding value: `DataContext.SelectedStudentItem`.

Make sense? But I can't get it right. But atleast I can get cells colours now. Just not quite what I want yet, until I can pass in the right `DataContext`.

### Update 2

I now have the binding correct so that I have the right DataContext:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingStudyPointsList}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Number}" />
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StudyPointWorkingOn}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag"/>
                        <Binding Path="DataContext" ElementName="oclmEditor" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

But I now have another problem. It is only constructing what the drop list looks like **once**. But I need it to be dynamic:

```
public Student SelectedStudentItem
{
    get
    {
        return _SelectedStudentItem;
    }
    set
    {
        // We need to remove this item from the previous student history
        if (_SelectedStudentItem != null)
            _SelectedStudentItem.History.Remove(Meeting.DateMeeting);

        _SelectedStudentItem = value;
        if (_SelectedStudentItem == null)
            return;

        _EditStudentButtonClickCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        _DeleteStudentButtonClickCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedStudentItem");

        if (ActiveStudentAssignmentType == StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingMain)
            _Meeting.BibleReadingMainName = _SelectedStudentItem.Name;
        else if (ActiveStudentAssignmentType == StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingClass1)
            _Meeting.BibleReadingClass1Name = _SelectedStudentItem.Name;
        else if (ActiveStudentAssignmentType == StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingClass2)
            _Meeting.BibleReadingClass2Name = _SelectedStudentItem.Name;
    }
}
```

Whenever the `SelectedStudentItem` property changes, I want the `ComboBoxItem' backgrounds to change accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it to work:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingStudyPointsList}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Number}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StudyPointWorkingOn}">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag"/>
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.SelectedStudentItem" ElementName="oclmEditor" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many solution to archive that.

a) You could wrap your `StudyPointItem` into a view model, give the view model a `Color` property and bind the `ComboBoxItem`'s background property to that color.

b) You could bind the item directly to the background property and use a converter to create the corresponding color for that items.

c) You could use a trigger to set the color if the property of the item has a certain value.

... I am sure that WPF provides even more possibilities.

Personally, I use converts for such tasks because they are very flexible and don't blow up the view models with any "converting properties".

Comment: I was thinking of a converter to just set the background. But to be able to do that I need 1. The value of the current `StudyPointItem.Number`, 2. The `Meeting` item from the right context, 3. The result of the `Meeting.IsWorkingOnStudyPoint(...)` call. I can't workout how I have access to all of that with XAML and a converter.

Comment: Yes, multibinding in combination with `IMultiValueConverter` is an option. Another option is to use item view models that know the context.